# Which php file lists all the post of a category

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy, archive-template

In my primary menu, I have added a category "News & Events" and when I click this page, I get all the posts of this category. Which `php` file I have to edit, in order to change some things that I don't want to appear when the posts are listed in that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses a [hierarchy of templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) (see the [visual overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)) which it checks for presence. In your case when showing a category archive it will check for presence the following files in this order and use the first one it finds:

- category-$slug.php (In your case probably category-news-events.php)
- category-$id.php
- category.php
- archive.php
- [paged.php] if paged
- index.php

So if you want to change things for a specific category, you best create a `category-$slug.php` (copy from `category.php`). If you want to to modify the general presentation of categories modify `category.php` directly. If `category.php` is not present, just use the next existing file according to the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit any file. Most of WordPress function can be hook with actions and filters.

Depending on where you want to display your posts, you'll need to search the most appopriate filter to make the job.

An example in your case can be:

I want to display 12 posts from category 'car'  except a few post ids (72,121)

```
   function exclude_single_posts($query) {
        if ($query->category_name == 'car' && $query->is_main_query()) {
              $query->set('post__not_in', array(72,121));
              $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
       }
   }

  add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts');
```

Put this on functions.php

There's many way change default arguments to change the query.

For more details search for actions and filters.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use https://wphierarchy.com/ to track down the file.

Interactive diagram for the [template hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
[image]